# How to export AD user properties with PowerShell to .csv file?

Tags: powershell, administrator, active-directory, csv, export

I have a problem exporting AD user properties to `.csv` file which are members of a particular AD group.

#### This is my code

```
$ExportPath= "C:\Users\group_list.csv"
$groupname = "group1"
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname | ? {$_.objectclass -eq "user"}
foreach ($activeusers in $users) { Get-ADUser -Identity $activeusers | ? {$_.enabled -ne $true} | select Name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, enabled, DistinguishedName | Format-Table} Export-Csv $ExportPath }
```

Comment: What is your question / problem? https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you have not asked a **_clearly defined question_** question ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just give `$Users` variable to pipeline where you select desired properties, and then pipeline it to `.csv` file.

```
$ExportPath = "C:\Users\group_list.csv"
$GroupName = "group1"
$Users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | ? {$_.objectclass -eq "user"}

$Users | ? {$_.enabled -ne $true} | select Name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, enabled, DistinguishedName | Export-Csv $ExportPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax issues with what you posted

```
$ExportPath = 'C:\Users\group_list.csv'
$groupname  = 'group1'
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname | 
         Where-Object {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'}

foreach ($activeusers in $users) 
{ 
    Get-ADUser -Identity $activeusers | 
    Where-Object {
    $_.enabled -ne $true} | 
    Select-Object Name, 
                  SamAccountName, 
                  UserPrincipalName, 
                  enabled, 
                  DistinguishedName | 
    Format-Table
} Export-Csv $ExportPath
```

A quick refactor of your posted code.

```
$ExportPath = 'C:\Users\group_list.csv'
$groupname  = 'group1'
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname | 
         Where-Object {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'}

foreach ($activeuser -in $users) 
{ 
    Get-ADUser -Identity $activeuser | 
    Where-Object {
    $PSItem.enabled -ne $true} | 
    Select-Object Name, 
                  SamAccountName, 
                  UserPrincipalName, 
                  enabled, 
                  DistinguishedName | 
    Export-Csv $ExportPath  -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

What 'Zoran Jankov' gave is more direct/less code, but be sure to add the '-NoTypeInformation' or you'll end up with some extra text in your output that you'll not want.

FYI...

Use the MS provided tools to write baseline code for you and use as is or tweak as needed.

- [Active Directory Administrative Center: Getting Started](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560651(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [Active Directory Administrative Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/adac/active-directory-administrative-center)
- [windows 'Active Directory Administrative Center'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%20%27Active%20Directory%20Administrative%20Center%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=windows%20%27active%20directory%20administrative%20center%27&sc=0-48&sk=&cvid=7953CBFABB4041D0AA7511F15E7C71CA)
- [windows 'Active Directory Administrative Center' 'PowerShell History
  Viewer'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%20%27Active%20Directory%20Administrative%20Center%27%20%27PowerShell%20History%20Viewer%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=windows%20%27active%20directory%20administrative%20center%27%20%27powershell%20h%27&sc=0-63&sk=&cvid=6A829C7678744459BBC33E999FDDC630)
- [Introduction to Active Directory Administrative Center](https://www.petri.com/use-active-directory-administrative-center-create-powershell-commands)
- [Use AD Administrative Center to Create PowerShell Commands](https://www.petri.com/use-active-directory-administrative-center-create-powershell-commands)
- [Step-By-Step: Utilizing PowerShell History Viewer in Windows Server
  2012 R2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/03/04/step-by-step-utilizing-powershell-history-viewer-in-windows-server-2012-r2)
- [Learning PowerShell with Active Directory Administrative Center
  (PowerShell History Viewer)](https://sid-500.com/2017/10/10/learning-powershell-with-active-directory-administrative-center-powershell-history-viewer)

Alias used in PowerShell scripts, should not be used, though they are fine for interactive/throw-away code, which is the purpose of them. If you do use them in your dev effort, be sure to expand them all before release or sharing. Here's why:

1. If you open this code in VSCode, it will make any alias as an error
   until you expand it.
2. If you run PSScriptAnalyzer against it, it too will call them out as
   errors.

Best Practice for Using Aliases in PowerShell Scripts

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/best-practice-for-using-aliases-in-powershell-scripts
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-powershell-aliases-best-practices

> **Why worry about aliases in the first place?**
>
> What is the big deal about using aliases anyway? If they make the code
> easier to type, what is the harm in using them in scripts? There are
> two things at work when it comes to a script. ***The first is that no
> alias is guaranteed to exist—even aliases that are created by Windows
> PowerShell.***

[Using PSScriptAnalyzer to check your PowerShell code for best practices](http://mikefrobbins.com/2015/11/19/using-psscriptanalyzer-to-check-your-powershell-code-for-best-practices)